# API Gateway + GovCloud + Custom Domain Name with SSL Cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am working in a govcloud account for client work and CANNOT use us-east-1 as it does not exist in govcloud. 
In the API Gateway console -> Custom Domain Names page the following text appears:
"To use an ACM certificate with API Gateway, you must request or import the certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) region."

How would I go about importing or creating a cert in ACM in us-east-1 as govcloud does not interact with that region?

How can I configure / script a custom domain name with api gateway in govcloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that message only applies to 'Edge Optimized' APIs which are not available in govcloud anyway. You can use a govcloud ACM cert with a Regional endpoint type.

Comment: excellent thanks. I was configuring the base path mapping wrong which prevented it from working.